# How to use i18next / react-i18next inside MDX / Markdown files with MDXJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, mdxjs

We use the [MDXJS](https://mdxjs.com/) package to write content in Markdown and use React components in it.

Is there a way of using the [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) / [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) package inside the MDX / Markdown files?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-markdown-jsx-plugin

Answer (score 7):

#### Using `i18next` inside `MDX`:

When you import an `MDX` file, you just use it as any other React component:

```
import { default as SomeContent } from './some-content.mdx';

...

<SomeContent />
```

Therefore, you can also pass down some props, in this case the `t` function, and use it inside in some specific ways:

```
import { default as SomeContent } from './some-content.mdx';

export const SomeComponent: React.FC = React.memo((props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <SomeContent t={ t } someProp="Some value" />
  );
});
```

If you want to check if this is working or see which props are accessible from within your `MDX` file, add this inside it:

```
<pre>{ JSON.stringify(props, null, '  ') }</pre>
<pre>{ typeof props.t }</pre>
```

For the example above, it will display:

```
{"someProp":"Some value"}
function
```

Note that you can't use these props inside "raw" `MD` elements, even if you add a wrapper around them:

```
### Doesn't work: { props.t('some.translation') }

Doesn't work: { props.t('some.translation') }.

Doesn't work: <>{ props.t('some.translation') }</>.

Doesn't work: <Fragment>{ props.t('some.translation') }</Fragment>.

Doesn't work: <span>{ props.t('some.translation') }</span>.
```

So you would have to write `HTML` tags instead:

```
<h3>Works: { props.t('some.translation') }</h3>

<p>Works: { props.t('some.translation') }.</p>

<p>Works: <>{ props.t('some.translation') }</>.</p>

<p>Works: <Fragment>{ props.t('some.translation') }</Fragment>.</p>

<p>Works: <span>{ props.t('some.translation') }</span>.</p>
```

#### Using `MDX` in `i18next`:

If you set [`returnObjects: true`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#translation-defaults) in your `i18next` config, you can also add `MDX` components inside your translation files:

```
import { default as ContentEN } from './content.en.mdx';
import { default as ContentES } from './content.es.mdx';

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        content: ContentEN,
      },
    },
    es: {
      translation: {
        content: ContentES,
      },
    },
  },

  returnObjects: true,
}));
```

And then you would use it like this in any of your components (and yes, you can also pass down `t` or any other prop, just as before:

```
export const SomeComponent: React.FC = React.memo((props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const Content = t('content');

  return (
    <Content t={ t } someProp="Some value" />
  );
});
```

#### Using `i18next` inside `@mdx-js/runtime`:

If you are using [`@mdx-js/runtime`](https://mdxjs.com/advanced/runtime), then you would pass down your props as `scope`:

```
import { default as SomeContent } from './some-content.mdx';

export const SomeComponent: React.FC = React.memo((props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <MDX components={ ... } scope={ { t, someProp: 'Some value' } }>{ props.mdx }</MDX>
  );
});
```