# Using GraphQL to query only markdown pages of language selected

Tags: graphql, internationalization, gatsby, netlify

Gatsby/GraphQL newbie building a bilingual site. My site (navbar, footer, body content etc) has all bilingual content in `en` and `zh` json files respectively, and calls the `t` function from `react-18next`. However, there are several pages in my website that have not been 'internationalised' yet - my markdown pages. As of current, the file structure looks like this:

```
src
├── posts
│   └── positions
│       ├── en
│       │   ├── accounting-en.md
│       │   ├── socialmedia-en.md
│       │   └── swe-en.md
│       └── zh
│           ├── accounting-zh.md
│           ├── socialmedia-zh.md
│           └── swe-zh.md
```

where the `.md` files are rendered onto the page with `MDXRenderer`, and i'd like only the contents in either the `en`/`zh` folders to load when either language is selected. I'd like to have these markdown files editable on Netlify CMS, so this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119525/how-to-use-i18next-react-i18next-inside-mdx-markdown-files-with-mdxjs) and `react-markdown` aren't things i'm considering.

so i was wondering: how can data from `i18n.language` be passed into a graphql query? is this the best way to internationalise markdown pages?

edits:

**gatsby-node.js**

```
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
    const { createNodeField } = actions

    if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
        const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })

        createNodeField({
            name: `slug`,
            node,
            value: `/posts${value}`,
            language,
        })
    }
}

const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => { // Create blog pages dynamically
    const { createPage } = actions
    const result = await graphql(`
        query {
            allMdx {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        fields {
                            slug
                            language
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    if (result.errors) {
        reporter.panicOnBuild('  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query')
    }

    // Create blog post pages.
    const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges

    posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
        createPage({
            path: node.fields.slug,
            component: path.resolve(`./src/components/post-page-template.js`),
            context: { id: node.id },
        })
    })
}
```

**posts.js** (where all markdown files are rendered, but i'd like only markdown files ending in either -en or -zh to show up depending on the language selected. i'm open to changing this file structure in favour of nicer code)

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby";

import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.js";
import FooterContainer from "../containers/footer";

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import i18next from "i18next";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: #ec1b2f;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

const Body = styled.body`
  margin-left: 6%;
`;

const Divider = styled.hr`
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 0;
  border-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 0px;

  &:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #ec1b2f;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
`;

// console.log('----')
// console.log(typeof i18next.language)// type string 
// console.log(i18next.language) // output: i18next: languageChanged zh-Hant

const selectedLanguage = i18next.language // this doesn't work despite i18next.language being type string??
const selectedLangRegex = selectedLanguage.split(/languageChanged (.*)/gm)


export const query = (selectedLangRegex) => graphql`
    query SITE_INDEX_QUERY {
        site {
            siteMetadata {
               title
               description
               language
            }
        }
        allMdx(
            sort: {fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC},
            filter: {frontmatter: {published: {eq: true}, language: {eq: selectedLangRegex}}} //trying to regex selectedLangRegex
        ){
            nodes {
                id
                excerpt(pruneLength: 250)
                frontmatter {
                    title
                    date(formatString: "DD MMM YYYY")
                }
                fields {
                    slug
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

const Careers = ({ props, data }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      {data.allMdx.nodes.map(({ excerpt, frontmatter, fields }) => (
        <Body>
          <Title>{frontmatter.title}</Title>
          <p>{frontmatter.date}</p>
          <p>{excerpt}</p>
          <Link to={fields.slug}>
            <Button>{t("careers.apply_button")}</Button>
          </Link>
          <Divider />
        </Body>
      ))}
      <FooterContainer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Careers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so i was wondering: how can data from `i18n.language` be passed into a
> graphql query? is this the best way to internationalise markdown
> pages?

Yes, of course. To me, passing a GraphQL variable to the template it's the cleanest and best way. In that way, you can add a fallback language (or leave it empty) to pick the non-internationalized file if it's not translated yet.

Something like:

```
const path = require("path")
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const queryResults = await graphql(`
    query getAllPosts {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        nodes {
          slug
          language #use relative/absolute path if needed
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const postTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/posts.js`)

  queryResults.data.allProducts.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
      path: `/blog/${node.slug}`,
      component: postTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
        language: node.language || 'en' // the fallback
      },
    })
  })
}
```

*Note: without knowing how your `gatsby-node.js` looks like you may need to tweak it a little bit the query as well as the `createPage` API.*

The idea is to query for a `language` field, which I'm assuming is a field of each post. If it's not, you can query for the file path (relative or absolute), which will contain the `en` or `zh` variable in its name. Adding the fallback language will force you to change all file names to send a valid variable.

Then, in your template (`posts.js`) you can use the `language` field as you are using the `slug` to filter each entity.

Comment: thanks! this is really helpful. querying the `language` field is such an elegant solution - however, i'm having issues adding language as a field to my frontmatter and passing the output of `i18next.language` to my query in `posts.js`. i've edited my post to include my `gatsby-node.js` and `posts.js`, do you think you could take a look?

Comment: also, is `node.slug`, `node.language` calling from a library?

Comment: `slug` and `language` come from the frontmatter of the MDX. You should add there the new field

Comment: i've managed to get it working, but string interpolation didn't work (afaik, data is fetched during runtime but queries + pages are compiled at build time) - i passed  `i18next.language` to the `onCreatePage` API and created a `en`/`zh` page for each language. is this what you had in mind or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Avoiding the build time would force you to tweak Gatsby's default behavior so, to me, that's the most elegant solution so far.